# How can I render children tags in a custom server control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, menu, servercontrols

I'm working on a custom ServerControl, I've created it like below :

```
[ParseChildren(true), PersistChildren(true)]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:Menu runat=\"server\"></{0}:Menu>")]
public class Menu : WebControl
{ 
    .....

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public MenuItem MenuItems { get; set; }
}

[ParseChildren(true), PersistChildren(true)]
public class MenuItem : WebControl
{ 
    ...... 

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public MenuItem SubMenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (_SubMenuItems == null) return new MenuItem();
            return _SubMenuItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _SubMenuItems = value;
        }
    }
    private MenuItem _SubMenuItems;

    [TemplateContainer(typeof(MenuItem))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate Template { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<%@ Register Assembly="JQueryMenu" Namespace="JQueryMenu" TagPrefix="MdsMenu" %>
<MdsMenu:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <AnimationItems AnimationSpeed="Fast" AnimationType="Opacity_Height" DropShadow="true"
        Delay="1000" />
    <MdsMenu:MenuItem ID="MenuItem1" runat="server" Text="MenuItem 01">
        <MdsMenu:MenuItem runat="server">
            <Template>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </Template>
        </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
    </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
    <MdsMenu:MenuItem ID="MenuItem2" runat="server" Text="MenuItem 01">
        <MdsMenu:MenuItem ID="MenuItem3" runat="server">
            <Template>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            </Template>
            <MdsMenu:MenuItem ID="MenuItem5" runat="server" Text="MenuItem 05">
            </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
            <MdsMenu:MenuItem ID="MenuItem6" runat="server" Text="MenuItem 06">
            </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
            <MdsMenu:MenuItem ID="MenuItem4" runat="server">
                <Template>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </Template>
            </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
        </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
    </MdsMenu:MenuItem>
</MdsMenu:Menu>
```

Now, How can I Parse it and render it in `RenderContent` method ? !!!
The following method is always throw the first Exception, it means this.Controls is always empty !!! 
How can I do it and how I can access to the nested children in `RenderControl` method ?

```
public class Menu : WebControl
{
    ....

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter output)
    { 
        if (!this.HasControls())
           throw new Exception("Controls are empty");
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey could you show me the rest of what your building Im making something similar Im having trouble with the collection part of MenuItem get set where you have subitems collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
```

to

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
```

`true` indicates that you want the children to be parsed as attributes/properties of your class, not children.

Comment: Thanks, What about `Template`, I wanna render some controls in `Template`. How can I do it ?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  Presumably you are setting the `Template` property to some new object, yes?  Is this a control you wrote?  If so, can you add the definition of this type to your question?

Comment: No, I'm using standard controls within `Template` tag, and I wanna to render them as usual. But I wanna to render above asp.net code, I mean `MdsMenu:MenuItem` tags.

Comment: Right, but what are you setting the Template property to in your code?  I assume you have to set it to something for the `<Template>...</Template>` markup to work.

Comment: this is my `Template` property : `[TemplateContainer(typeof(MenuItem))]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public ITemplate Template { get; set; }`

Comment: But do you **set** the property to anything?  Like in a constructor?